# React Component - set page title

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

> jsx Code Here:

```
class PaperList extends React.Component{
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      newsList: [{
        title:'title1',
        content:'content1'
      },{
        title:'title2',
        content:'content2'
      }]
    };
  }
render() {
var that = this;
    var lists = this.state.newsList.map(function(news,idx){
      return <Paper key={idx} style={paperStyle} zDepth={2}><h2>{that.state.newsList['+idx+'].title}</h2></Paper>;
    });
    return (<div>
      {lists}
    </div>
    );
  }
```

If only has **that.state.newsList['+idx']** , is no problem .
how to get the title ?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to access the array through the index when using a Array.map(). In your case `news` is the item in the array at current index `idx`. There is no need to find the item using the `idx` value from this.state.newsList. The code below should work to get the title.

```
var lists = this.state.newsList.map( function( news, idx ) {
   return (
      <Paper key={idx} style={paperStyle} zDepth={2}>
         <h2>{news.title}</h2>
      </Paper>
   );
})
```